# Get value for checkbox in html/php from database(mysql)

Tags: php, html

I have data stored in database in varchar format like for eg: S,M,L,XL , I have checkboxes for these in my php page. Is it possible to retrieve these from database and show already checked boxes in php/html. (When there is just XL value , only XL checkbox should be checked in html/php page )

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in my project and I do not recommend.

You can store an enum array of values in PHP and then use it to create the form. Selecting the data from database is not different than any other query. You can then compare the value from the database to the value in your array.

```
define('SIZES', ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL']);
$value_from_db = 'L'; // Fetched from the database

echo '<form>';
foreach (SIZES as $size) {
    if ($value_from_db == $size) {
        echo '<label><input type="checkbox" value="' . $size . '" name="size" checked />' . $size . '</label>';
    } else {
        echo '<label><input type="checkbox" value="' . $size . '" name="size" />' . $size . '</label>';
    }
}
```

A better option would be to store these values in a reference table in the database instead of in PHP. You can then enforce the referential integrity. Instead of looping on the array, you would loop on the values from the reference table.

Answer (score -2):

One way of doing is :
- you retrieve the database values using SQL in PHP 
- Dynamically create the checkbox HTML using the retrieved values

Comment: Why this is downvoted ? I know this is a very elementary question but id the answer is not correct reason must be there..